# SQL Server : sorting NULL Marks with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, null, sql-order-by

I have this query :

```
SELECT orderid, shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 20
ORDER BY shippedate;
```

and the output is:

```
orderid shippeddate
------- -----------
11008   NULL
11072   NULL
10258   2006-07-23 00:00:00.000
10263   2006-07-31 00:00:00.000
10351   2006-11-20 00:00:00.000
10368   2006-12-02 00:00:00.000
...
```

As an exercise, I am trying to figure out how to sort the orders by `shippeddate` ascending, but have NULLs sort last.

I know that `standard SQL` support the options `NULL FIRST` and `NULL LAST`, but `T-SQL` doesn't support this option.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT orderid, shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 20
ORDER BY case when shippeddate is null then 2 else 1 end, shippedate;
```

Comment: what it does ? `case when shippeddate is null then 2 else 1 end`

Comment: It returns 1 when shippeddate is not null and 2 otherwise, and that is used for sorting

Answer (score 0):

In addition,

You could replace value in the field if it is null by using ISNULL

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

So your query would look something like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(orderid, '1900-01-01'), 
       shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 20 
ORDER BY shippedate asc;
```

So this would replace any NULLs in that field with a value (1900-01-01 in this case) you could sort on

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP wants. All this does is replace NULL with a fake date. It does NOT get the rows sorted correctly.